# android - is it possible to use private intents instead of global ones?

Tags: android, android-intent, global, private, public

background:
i've noticed that for regular activities within, it is possible for any application to open the activities of my app .

question:
is it possible to allow only my own app (or apps , or package) to send and receive intents inside the same scope , so that other application won't be able to receive them or interfere with the flow of the app?

example:
suppose i have a broadcastReceiver that listens to some kind of intent , but this intent is only meant to be used by another service/activity that resides either inside my app , or inside another app that i've created , but i don't want others to be able to use this intent.

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> suppose i have a broadcastReceiver that listens to some kind of intent , but this intent is only meant to be used by another service/activity that resides either inside my app , or inside another app that i've created , but i don't want others to be able to use this intent.

In addition to Reno's fine answer, for your specific requirement quoted above, use `LocalBroadcastManager`. Not only do you get the security you seek, but it is more efficient. `LocalBroadcastManager` is available in the Android Support package and AFAIK should work going back to Android 1.6. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Local) using `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: could you pleas tell some more? how come it's faster? how does it work? is it like sending the object directly? if so , is it also recommended in order to send rapid (in high-frequency) data between an activity and a service ?

Answer (score 6):

[`setPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29)

> Set an explicit application package name that limits the components this Intent will resolve to. If left to the default value of null, all components in all applications will considered. If non-null, the Intent can only match the components in the given application package.

or you can use `setSelector()` , but not both.

Comment: when should i use each of them, and what are the advantages & disadvantages of using them?

Comment: also , what about restricting the activities of my app , so that they won't be able to be launched from another app? maybe something in the manifest?

Comment: Please [read this first](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). One way I can think of is to check for an extra. Kind of like a token, if the token passed is the one you're expecting: launch the activity.

Comment: do you mean that i put a password mechanism of some kind , which is checked on the onCreate() method of the launched activity ? i was hoping for a simple manifest solution . sure there isn't such a thing?